# Conseguir Mostrar Produtos de um Utilizador

Tags: php, html, mysqli, banco-de-dados

Boas!

É o seguinte, eu estou a desenvolver um website que consiste em um utilizador ver o estado do seu equipamento enquanto está a ser reparado. Mas estou a ter dificuldades a visualizar o produto de um certo utilizador para ele.

Por exemplo: O administrador insere um produto na base de dados com um certo ID, e depois o cliente loga-se no website e deveria de conseguir visualizar o seu produto...

criei as seguintes tabelas -> Utilizadores, Equipamentos e utilizador_equipamento.

Eis o que eu fiz:

DataAcess.php ( Serve para ligar a base de dados )

Função para ir buscar os registos:

```
function getRegistos(){

    $query = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),dataDeEntrada) as diferenca FROM `equipamentos` WHERE 1";
    $this->connect();
    $res = $this->execute($query);
    $this->disconnect();
    return $res;

}
```

Função para inserir registo

```
function inserirRegisto($id_utilizador, $nome, $tipo, $estado, $marca, $modelo, $sintoma, $orcamento) {
        $query = "insert into equipamentos 
                    (id_utilizador, nome, tipo, estado, marca, modelo, sintoma, orcamento)
                    values 
                    ('$id_utilizador', '$nome','$tipo','$estado','$marca', '$modelo','$sintoma','$orcamento')";
        $this->connect();
        $this->execute($query);
        $this->disconnect();
}
```

E depois para ir buscar os registos fiz isto:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
include_once('DataAccess.php');
$da = new DataAccess();
$res = $da->getEquipamento($id);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){ ... }
```

Preciso de ir buscar todos os equipamentos de um certo utilizador pelo seu ID mas não sei como posso fazê-lo. Sei que a tabela utilizador_equipamento me vai ajudar mas ainda não sei como.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Era mais fácil se associasses a cada equipamento um utilizador. Adicionavas o campo `user_id` à tabela de equipamentos:

```
insert into equipamentos 
            (nome, tipo, estado, marca, modelo, sintoma, orcamento, user_id) ...
```

E depois era só fazer o `SELECT` assim:

```
$query =
"SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),dataDeEntrada) as diferenca ".
"FROM `equipamentos` ".
"WHERE user_id='$id_utilizador'";
```